# Error when trying to acces dbf files throught SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server, visual-foxpro

I am trying to do single query to a dbf(FoxPro 9) file through
SqlServer, the problem is that this files are located in another domain, so i configured a LinkedServer with a valid remote user and a remote password in the security page of the linked server, and when i try to execute the query i get the error:"Invalid path or file name", but if i open the Windows explorer and go to the location of the dbf files, then i close the explorer and launch again the query, now Works fine, i don't know why, Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work, if you need to connect using a username and password. If the remote location allows connecting without a username and password then it would work, that is why it works after you manually make the connection. Use a mapped drive as a workaround. OTOH linked server to VFP is not much of a value, I doubt it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks, now works perfect!!

Anyway(only for curiosity) if doen't work puting the user and password in the linked server  for what is used this option?

Answer (score 1):

If authorization is correct it may be a problem with mapped drives.  The query is executed on the server so that machine needs to have access.  Have  you tried windows explorer on the server?  Have you tried a UNC path?

Comment: I don´t use mapped drives, i use UNC, in the Linked Server i put in the Data origin:      \\192.192.192.1\d\soft

Comment: Have you used windows explorer on the server?

Comment: Yes if i use the Windows explorer i don't have any problema to acces the files, when i open the Windows explorer and go to the location of the files they ask me for a user and password, i put the same of i putted in the linked server and i can see all the files, and if execute the query after this, the query Works fine, this is strange.